# How to turn a pty shell into a remote shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to implement a remote shell POC similar to ssh without the decryption that supports interactive usage and authentication with sudo
here is the client part

```
int main()
{
    /* created client socket and connected to the server  */
    // Create pseudo terminal 
    if (openpty(&master, &slave, NULL, NULL, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror("failed to find pseudo terminal");
        close(client_socket);
        return -1;
    }
    // fork process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("failed to fork process");
        close(client_socket);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close (master);
        setsid();
        ioctl(slave, TIOCSCTTY, 0);

        dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(slave, STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(slave, STDERR_FILENO);

        execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", NULL);
        perror("failed to start bash shell");
    }
    else
    {
        close(slave);
        while(1)
        {
            ibytes = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (ibytes)
            {
                obytes = write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, ibytes); 
                printf("%ld>%s<", obytes, buffer);
            }
        }
        int status; 
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        close(master);
    }
    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

as the server

```
int main()
{
    /* created server socket, binded, listening */
    while (1)
    {
        addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_size);
        if (client_socket > 0 )
        {
            printf("New client connection \n");
        }

        bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (bytes)
            write(client_socket, buffer, bytes); 

        bytes = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (bytes)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bytes); 
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }
    close(server_socket);
    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to be able to use this shell from the server to use programs such as nano, vim and be able to elevate using sudo.

Comment: You don't create the pty on the client, you create it on the server. The client already has a real tty, it doesn't need a pty.

Comment: [This](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2018-02-24/0/POSTING-en.html) might be helpful

Comment: @Barmar could you elaborate more, maybe with overview steps on how to achieve such objective.

Comment: On the server you create a pty. Then fork a shell whose stdin, stdout, and stderr are duped to the slave end of the pty. The server relays between the pty master and the network.

Comment: @barmar Just to be sure, the server should be controlling the remote shell to the client, what ever command is insert in the server should be executed on the remote client

Comment: That happens when it relays between the pty and the socket.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood. It sounds like you're trying to implement a reverse shell.

Comment: You said this was like SSH, but it's the opposite of SSH.

Comment: @barmar like SSH in a sense where you can interact with the different cli binaries, here is an attempt at what i understood from what you mentioned [server](https://pastebin.com/raw/x0MZywfy) [client](https://pastebin.com/raw/LuvpUeAB)

Comment: Anyway, if you google "how to implement reverse shell" you'll find some tutorials.

Comment: @Barmar `but it's the opposite of SSH` HSS?